# Comment on wordpress with XML-RPC from Android

Tags: java, android, wordpress

I know it's possible to publish a post through RPC in wordpress, but is it possible to post comment on blog post in simmilar way from Java/Android application.

I have already tried to post comment from android application through httppost but it's not working for me because post request must contain akismet nonce. Also i have read some threads here on Stackoverflow but nothing came up.